# Justifying $f(x,y) = xy$ is continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I justify that $f(x,y) = xy$ is continuous based on the following?

> A composition of continuous functions is continuous. That is, assume that $S\subseteq R^n$ and $T \subseteq R^k $, and that $f: S \mapsto R^k $ and $g: T \mapsto R^q$ are functions such that $g \circ f$ is well-defined. If $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $g$ is continous at $f(a)$, then $g \circ f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: This is not a composition of functions in any helpful way. Why do you think it should be based on that? Ultimately, you need to know that multiplication is continuous as a map $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, and that's precisely what this is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that $f:\textbf{R}^{2}\to\textbf{R}$ is given by $f(x,y) = xy$.

Thus we can make use of the following statements which are equivalent

> (a) Let $f:(X,d_{X})\to(Y,d_{Y})$ be a continuous function.
>
> (b) Whenever  $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X$ which converges to $x_{0}$ with respect to the metric $d_{X}$, the sequence $(f(x_{n}))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f(x_{0})$ with respect to $d_{Y}$.

At your case, $X = \textbf{R}^{2}$ and $Y = \textbf{R}$.

Moreover, we have the following additional result

> Let $(x^{(k)})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\textbf{R}^{n}$. Then $x^{(k)} = (x^{(k)}_{1},x^{(k)}_{2},\ldots,x^{(k)}_{n})$ converges to $x = (x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})$ in the metric $d_{1}$, $d_{2}$ or $d_{\infty}$ iff $x^{(k)}_{j}$ converges to $x_{j}$.

**Proposition**

The function $f:\textbf{R}^{2}\to\textbf{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = xy$ is continuous.

**Proof**

Let us consider a convergent sequence $x_{k} = (a_{k},b_{k})\in(\textbf{R}^{2},d_{2})$, where $d_{2}$ is the euclidean metric. Since $x_{k}$ converges, say, to $x = (a,b)$, the same applies to $a_{k}$ and $b_{k}$, that is to say, $a_{k}\to a$ and $b_{k}\to b$. Due to the properties of sequential convergence, we conclude that $a_{k}b_{k}$ converges to $ab$. In other words,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(a_{k},b_{k}) = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_{k}b_{k} = ab = f(a,b)
\end{align*}

Hence we conclude that $f$ is continuous, and we are done.